# NextJS: Warning: Prop target did not match. Server: "_top" Client: "_blank"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm building a blog with this framework and two days I got the next warning from nothing(I didn't get it before):

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2273 Warning: Prop `target` did not match. Server: "_top" Client: "_blank"
    in a (at url.js:16)
    in Link (at url.js:15)
    in li (created by ForwardRef(ListItem))
    in ForwardRef(ListItem) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(ListItem)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(ListItem)) (at url.js:14)
    in URL (at footer.js:77)
    in ul (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at footer.js:74)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at footer.js:73)
    in footer (created by ForwardRef(Container))
    in ForwardRef(Container) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Container)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Container)) (at footer.js:72)
    in Footer (at _app.js:46)
    in ThemeProvider (at _app.js:42)
    in FolioApp (created by withI18nextSSR(FolioApp))
    in withI18nextSSR(FolioApp) (created by AppWithTranslation)
    in NextStaticProvider (created by withI18nextTranslation(NextStaticProvider))
    in withI18nextTranslation(NextStaticProvider) (created by AppWithTranslation)
    in I18nextProvider (created by AppWithTranslation)
    in AppWithTranslation (created by withRouter(AppWithTranslation))
    in withRouter(AppWithTranslation)
    in ErrorBoundary (created by ReactDevOverlay)
    in ReactDevOverlay (created by Container)
    in Container (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in Root
```

The component is:

```
import { Link, ListItemIcon, ListItem } from "@material-ui/core"

---

    <ListItem className={classes.inlineBlock}>
      <Link href={"//" + url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
          <ListItemIcon style={{ minWidth: minimize ? "inherit" : "" }}>
            {
              {
                Home: <Home />,
                Github: <GitHub />,
                BitBucket: <BitBucket />,
                GitLab: <GitLab />,
                StackOverflow: <StackOverflow />,
                LinkedIn: <LinkedIn />,
              }[type]
            }
          </ListItemIcon>
      </Link>
    </ListItem>
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved by updating **NextJS** and following the [**Material UI**'s example.](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs)